# Stop Video Slideshow on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make a simple slideshow script pause when someone clicks on the slideshow?

I have a slideshow of Youtube videos that cycle through with this script:

```
setInterval() { 
$('#videoSlides > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(2000)
.end()
.appendTo('#videoSlides');
},  15000);};
```

HTML as follows (container div, plus 3 child divs each containing an embedded youtube video):

```
<div id="videoSlides">
<div class="videoSlide"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoID"></iframe></div>
<div class="videoSlide"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoID"></iframe></div>
<div class="videoSlide"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoID"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

So, while the slideshow is flipping between the 3 videos, and someone clicks on one of the videos, that slideshow should stop there on that slide. How do I make this happen?

Comment: Best way to do this is to tie into [YouTube's event listeners](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers are pointing in the right direction, you should be aware of another thing: Catching the click event from the embedded youtube players is not as easy as suggested because the click event is not propagated outside of the player.

A simple workaround is to use the mouseenter event instead, like so:

```
$('#videoSlides').mouseenter(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

But that might not yield the behavior you want.

Another more complicated way to go is to use the youtube player api to catch the state change when the video starts. You can find more information [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de).

I put together an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b5r2fa9/1/) ***(don't forget to insert your video IDs in the HTML part first!)***

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
var interval=setInterval(function() { 
    $('#videoSlides > div:first')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#videoSlides');
}, 15000)};

$('#videoSlides').click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Voting not to delete this, but you need to add an explanation.

Comment: This is the right way of stopping the slideshow, but catching the click event won't work this way. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296271/stop-video-slideshow-on-click/25296746#25296746) for a solution to that problem.

Comment: @AndyM I thought it was pretty obvious as intervals are the basics of JS

Comment: Maybe you did, but it's in the Low Quality Posts queue for a reason. Throwing down some code without explaining what it does and why it works typically doesn't help the OP as much as explaining would.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to stop your interval from running. To do so, when you set it, assign it to a variable. Then you can use `clearInterval` like so:

```
var mySlideShow = window.setInterval(function(){
    [Your transition code]
}, 15000);

//on click
window.clearInterval(mySlideShow);
```

Comment: This is the right way of stopping the slideshow, but the tricky part will be catching the click event. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296271/stop-video-slideshow-on-click/25296746#25296746) for a solution to that problem.